# Attributes and count() in xpath expression

Tags: xml, xpath, count

Given the following XML file :

```
<a m="1">
    <b n="1" o="2">
        <c p="3">3</c>
        <d/>
    </b>
    <b n="1" o="2">
        <c p="3">3</c>
        <d q="3">
            <e r="2">2</e>
        </d>
        <f s="1"/>
    </b>
</a>
```

How can I find the following expressions :

```
1. count(/*/*/*)  =  5
2. count (/*//*)  = 6
3. count (/*/*//@*) = 4
```

I ran the xml file with those xpath expressions in Java , but I don't understand why the answers are 5,6,4 .

Can someone please explain how can I calculate the above expressions (not using a java code) but by understanding the actual concept of the commands `/*/*/*` and `/*//*` and `/*/*//@*` ?

Much appreciated

Comment: Presumably this exercise comes *after* some teaching material on xpath? Did you feel you understood the teaching material?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
/*/*/*
```

This selects all "grand-children of the top element -- these are: `c`, `d`, `c`, `d`

```
/*//*
```

This selects all descendant elements of the top element: `b`, `c`, `d`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e`, `f`

```
/*/*//@*
```

This selects all attributes either of children of the top element or of their descendants: `n`, `o`, `p`, `n`, `o`, `p`, `q`, `r`, `s`.

Therefore, the counts produced must be, respectively:

```
4, 8, 9
```

**XSLT - based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:value-of select="count(/*/*/*)"/>
=========
   <xsl:value-of select="count(/*//*)"/>
=========
   <xsl:value-of select="count(/*/*//@*)"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is performed on the provided XML document** (never, *never* ever present the document with a picture!!!):

```
<a m="1">
 <b n="1" o="2">
   <c p="3">3</c>
   <d/>
 </b>
 <b n="1" o="2">
   <c p="3">3</c>
   <d q="3">
     <e r="2">2</e>
   </d>
 </b>
 <f s="1"/>
</a>
```

**The Xpath expressions are evaluated and their results are copied to the output**:

```
   4
=========
   8
=========
   9
```

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev If you are going to promote your product in comments, then you *must* disclose your affiliation with that product.  If not, then those comments must be deleted.

Answer (score 3):

1- Find direct descendant of elements which are direct descendant of direct descendants of root element
In this case

```
/a/b[1]/c
/a/b[1]/d

/a/b[2]/c
/a/b[2]/d
/a/b[2]/f
```

are your answer.

2- all descendant (direct or indirect) element under first level of elements
In this case

```
/a/b[1]/c
/a/b[1]/d

/a/b[2]/c
/a/b[2]/d
/a/b[2]/d/e
/a/b[2]/f
```

are your answer.

3- find all attributes which belong all descendants of direct descendants of first level elements
In this case

```
/b[1]/@n
/b[1]/@o
/b[1]/c/@p

/b[2]/@n
/b[2]/@o
/b[2]/c/@p
/b[2]/d/@q
/b[2]/d/e/@r
/b[2]/f/@s
```

are your answer.

As you can see here answer to 3rd case is 9, since you wrote it wrong. To make it return your must change it as `count(/*/*/*/@*)`

**EDIT**: corrected indices as noted by Mimo.

Comment: you may try and see the results in http://www.whitebeam.org/library/guide/TechNotes/xpathtestbed.rhtm

Comment: Minor qubble: in XPath the numbering of nodes starts from 1, not from 0 - it would be better to write `/b[1]/@n`, `/b[2]/@n` etc.

Comment: @edokan: Thanks . When I say `/*` , that means that I want to go one level below ? and `/*/*` is to levels below ?

Comment: @edokan: BTW ,we were both wrong ,for the first one , it's `8` and not `6` , since it also includes : `a/b[1]` and `a/b[2]` .

Comment: When you say '/*' it means all first level elements. Since "there can be only one" first level element, it is same as '/'. In your xml, selecting '/*' should return '/a'. selecting '/*/*' means children of root.

Comment: @edokan, this answer is quite far from the truth.

Comment: @Dimitre, could you please explain further?

Comment: @edokan, The XPath expressions given by the OP, which are the arguments of the `count()` function, don't select the node-sets in your answer -- everyone can see this by evaluating them. As result of this, the counts you report aren't correct. You report these counts: 5, 6, 9. But the true counts, produced by evaluating the three XPath expressions are: 4, 8, 9. Also, you are using non-conventional terminology. XPath uses the term "child" and "children" -- not "direct descendant(s)". In a comment you make the incorrect statement that "/* ... it is the same as /".

Answer (score 0):

Run your java code again but without the count function.  You'll get back a list of nodes (sometimes elements and sometime attributes).  Iterate over the list and write out the name of each node.  That will help you understand which of the nodes are included in each of the counts.