# Xpath decendant-or-self with attribute

Tags: xml, xpath, count

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Attributes and count() in xpath expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988929/attributes-and-count-in-xpath-expression)

Having follow xml -

```
 <a m="1">
    <b n="1" o="2">
      <c p="3">3</c>
      <d/>
    </b>
    <b n="1" o="2">
      <c p="3">3</c>
      <d q="3">
        <e r="2">2</e>
      </d>
      <f s="1"/>
    </b>
  </a>
```

Why does `count(/*/*//@*) = 9`   ?

Can someone count all the nodes retrieved by order ?

Comment: I will repeat what I said to your ?classmate in the dupe question: Presumably this exercise comes *after* some teaching material on xpath? Did you feel you understood the teaching material?

Comment: @AakashM you right this is a same Q , vote to close this post  . thanks .

Comment: You should get your teacher to join stack overflow, s/he'd gain a lot of reputation points just by answering the class's questions here.

Answer (score 0):

> Why does `count(/*/*//@*)` = 9

**Because**

```
/*/*//@*
```

selects all any attribute of any element that is a child of the top element of the XML document, or that is a descendant of a child of the top element of the XML document.

The selected attributes are all attributes in the XML document with the exception of `m` which is the only attribute of the  top element: `n`, `o`, `p`, `n`, `o`, `p`, `q`, `r`, `s` .

And the count of the above is 9.